# referencing drawable size and rendering drawables adjacent to one another

Tags: android, canvas, bitmap, rendering

I'm working on a game that uses a 2D tile map. The map is rendered via a custom method doDraw() in a SurfaceView. It's a simple double for loop that gets the tile type from a 2D array, determines the corresponding bitmap for that type, then draws the tile to the canvas at the specified coordinates.

Previously I had placeholder .pngs in my drawable folder. These placeholder drawables were simple 100x100 .png files of solid colors that I created in ms paint. Things appeared to be working fine until I swapped out the placeholder drawables with some nice textured drawables. I then realized that the way I was referencing the coordinates to draw the tiles was incorrect and was actually causing them to overlap. This had not been obvious when the tiles were solid colors, but with textures it became pretty obvious that two sides of the tiles were getting covered by adjacent tiles.

I believe the problem is not actually in my doDraw() method but most likely in the way I am referencing the tile sizes. The .png files are 100x100 but they are probably getting converted to a different size based on the pixel density of my device. I think that's what's going on, and I've been reading up how to deal with that, but everything I'm finding out there will generally be talking about a single bitmap, as opposed to many small bitmaps that need to be drawn relative to each other.

Here's the relevant code from my SurfaceView:

```
public class MapView extends SurfaceView implements SurfaceHolder.Callback {

protected Context context;
public World world;
public Map<Integer,Bitmap> TILE_MAP;
public Bitmap SPRITE;
public Player player;
public Camera camera;

//hardcoded parameters for testing
private int tile_width = 50;
private int tile_height = 50;
public int screen_width = 12; //specifies how many tiles to draw in y direction
public int screen_height = 6; //specifies how many tiles to draw in x direction

public MapThread mapThread; 

public MapView(Context context, AttributeSet attrs) {

    super(context, attrs);
    this.context = context;
    Log.d("LOGCAT", "MapView created"); 

    //get the tile map
    WorldFeatures worldFeatures = new WorldFeatures(context);       
    TILE_MAP = worldFeatures.TILE_MAP;
    SPRITE = worldFeatures.SPRITE;

    SurfaceHolder holder = getHolder();
    holder.addCallback(this);

}

public void doDraw(Canvas canvas) {

    /*the draw method looks a little muddled at the moment as my camera is referencing 
    the center tile instead of the top left tile. I'll be updating that soon*/

    int screenX = 0; //reset screenX each loop 

    for (int worldX = (camera.x - screen_height/2 + 1); worldX < (camera.x + screen_height/2 + 1); worldX += 1, screenX += 1) {

        int screenY = 0; //reset screenY each loop 

        for (int worldY = (camera.y - screen_width/2 + 1);  worldY < (camera.y + screen_width/2 + 1); worldY += 1, screenY += 1) {

            canvas.drawBitmap(TILE_MAP.get(world.world_map[worldX][worldY]), screenY*tile_height , screenX*tile_width, null);

            if (player.x == worldX && player.y == worldY) { //if the player is standing here, draw the sprite
                canvas.drawBitmap(SPRITE, screenY*tile_height + tile_height/5, screenX*tile_width + tile_width/5, null);

            }

        }
    }


}

    }
```

As you can see above, I've hardcoded the tile height and width. A means to abstract this would be nice, but first I'd like to understand what the correct numbers to use are. If I set the height and width for the tiles to 100, I get spaces between the tiles. If set them to 50, I get overlap. This tells me that the correct size to reference is something in between. I could keep guessing until I get it right, but I'd like to understand how to determine what size my drawables scale to for what pixel density.

Currently my drawables are residing in my drawable-hdpi folder, and nowhere else. I'm wondering if I put them in a generic "drawable" folder, will I be able to reference the tile_height and tile_width as 100x100? I've read up on getting intrinsic height and width but that doesn't help when the bitmaps are scaled for the view or device. Even if it's possible to somehow reference the tile sizes based on the original drawable size, I would think there should be a better way than referencing them by any specific number. Shouldn't I be able to find out what the scaled size is while inside my draw method? And then use that to determine what coordinates to draw the tiles to? Even better, is there a way to force what size I want the bitmap to scale to before I draw it to the canvas?

I've read up on pixel density, dpi, drawable folders, etc. at http://developer.android.com/guide/practices/screens_support.html but this doesn't really help me when I'm drawing tiles relative to each other and therefore needing coordinates.

I've also looked into using Rectangles to draw to the canvas since the drawbitmap() method of Canvas that takes Rectangles as an input is not dependent on pixel density. But I'm unsure how practical using Rectangles would be when I have a 12x6 set of tiles to draw. Would I need one Rectangle per tile location?

Any explanations on dealing with scaled bitmaps and/or a better method to draw what I'm drawing would be most helpful.

Answer (score 1):

Answered my own question after getting some sleep. To get the height of a bitmap after android has scaled it automatically, use getWidth() and getHeight() on the Bitmap. For forcing a bitmap to scale to a specific size, use scaleBitmap()